# Erro no Linux Cinnamon

Tags: linux

Instalei há 03 semanas o Linux Cinnamon 18.2 (Sonya), porém hoje apareceu um alerta dizendo que ocorreu um erro e que o Cinnamon seria reiniciado. Após isso, por desencargo de consciência, decidi reiniciar também o notebook. Só que agora o gerenciador de atualizações está aparecendo esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao tentar o comando:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 97C215EF
sudo apt update
```

Apareceu no primeiro comando a mensagem:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.S24tOjXm89/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
pgp.mit.edu
--recv-keys
97C215EF
gpg: requisitando chave 97C215EF de servidor hkp - pgp.mit.edu
gpgkeys: key 97C215EF not found on keyserver
gpg: nenhum dado OpenPGP válido encontrado.
gpg: Número total processado: 0
gpg: erro de comunicação com o keyserver: key not found
gpg: erro de comunicação com o keyserver: chave pública incorreta
gpg: Recebimento de informação do keyserver falhou: chave pública incorreta
```

E no segundo do update depois de ler todos os pacotes:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
W: Falhou ao buscar http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
W: Falhou o download de alguns ficheiros de índice. Foram ignorados ou os antigos foram usados em seu lugar.
```

Como faço para corrigir esse erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em relação ao erro da chave, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

> Baixei a chave pública
>   http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg, depois
>   fui em Fontes de aplicativos >> chaves de autentificação e adicionei a
>   chave que baixei.